# Java: need advise about WeakHashMap

Tags: java, caching, weakhashmap

I guess I'm another person trying to make some kind of a cache with WeakHashMap. And I need some help with it.

I have bunch of `TrackData` objects that contain information about audio tracks. Then there are `Track` objects that keep reference to the `TrackData` inside. Several tracks can point to the same `TrackData`. Then I have `TrackDataCache` class that looks like this:

```
public class TrackDataCache {
private static TrackDataCache instance = new TrackDataCache();

public static TrackDataCache getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private WeakHashMap<TrackData, WeakReference<TrackData>> cache = new WeakHashMap<TrackData, WeakReference<TrackData>>();

public void cache(Track track) {
    TrackData key = track.getTrackData();
    WeakReference<TrackData> trackData = cache.get(key);
    if (trackData == null) {
        cache.put(key, new WeakReference<TrackData>(key));
    } else {
        track.setTrackData(trackData.get());
    }
}
}
```

So when I load a track, I call `TrackDataCache.cache()` and if its track data was not loaded before, it is cached or replaced with cached copy otherwise (`TrackData` overrides equals() method to check for location and subsong index). I want to use weak references so that I don't need to care when I remove Tracks.

I wanted to ask if it is an ok practice to keep weak reference to the key in WeakHashMap, and if not, how should I approach this problem? I need weak references and constant time retrieving of cached values. I was thinking of copying WeakHashMap code and making `getEntry()` method public, which solves the problem but it's such a bad hack :(

PS. I understand that either apache or google collections may have something like this, but I really don't want to add 2Mb dependencies.

Comment: Do you need WeakSet? Read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062919/why-does-exist-weakhashmap-but-absent-weakset

Comment: @Stas Kurilin: I need to be able to get objects without iterating, so Set doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to replace `WeakReferences` with [`SoftReferences`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html).

Any objects which is referenced only by a `WeakReference` is a target for every round of the garbage collector. It means that your cache can be cleared even it there's still enough free memory.

If you replace `WeakReference` with `SoftReference` then you state: Remove referenced object only when there's absolutely no free memory to allocate.

There's no ready-to-use `SoftHashMap` implementation in java. There is a good example in guava - [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html). It's worth to use this well-tested and verified on production environments code and not to provide your own definitely less quality implementation. It also has amazing mechanism of 'self-cleaning':

1. you can specify [cache max size](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#maximumSize%28int%29):

   > As the map size grows close to the
   >   maximum, the map will evict entries
   >   that are less likely to be used again.
   >   For example, the map may evict an
   >   entry because it hasn't been used
   >   recently or very often.
2. you can specify expiration time for map entries with `expireAfterWrite` and `expireAfterAccess` methods.

I also find your cache design not very convenient. As I understand from your code snippet, from start your `Track`s have strong references to their `TrackData` and you build your cache upon these circumstances. But from *some* moment you want to use your cache for retreiving data so you'll have to create new `Track`s in some other way because from *that* moment you want to use cache but not strong references.

Different `Tracks` can have the same `TrackData` so we can't use `Track` as a key. So, I'd go with the next approach:

1. introduce intermediate ids level and make cache based on the `Map<Integer, TrackData>` with soft values and defined self-cleaning strategy (based on `MapMaker`);
2. change relation `Track --> TrackData` to `Track --> Id (int)`. Cache `Id --> TrackData`.

Answer (score 1):

`TrackData` can be shared by many instances of `Track`. We need to have a key system that doesn't require `TrackData` to obtain the same instance for several `Track`.

```
 public class Track [

   @Override
   public int hashcode() {
     ... make hashcode that will be the same for
     ... tracks sharing the same track data.
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals() {
     ... ensure that if A.hashcode == B.hashcode then A.equals(B)
   }

 }

 public class TrackDataManager {

   private WeakHashMap<Track,TrackData> cache = new WeakHashMap<Track,TrackData>();

   public TrackData getTrackData(Track track) {

     // Track.hashcode()/equals() ensures two tracks that
     // share track data will get the same object back
     TrackData data = cache.get(track);

     if (data == null) {

       data = constructDataFromTrackFile(track);

       cache.put(track, data);

     }

     return data;

   }

   private TrackData constructDataFromTrackFile(Track track) {
     ... read data from file and create that object.
   }

 }
```

If the construction of the `TrackData` object is always going to happen as part of reading the file, but the created instance is being thrown away in favour of the shared instance, I'd model that like this:

```
 public class TrackData {

   @Override
   public int hashcode() {
     ... make hashcode that will be the same for same track data.
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals() {
     ... ensure that if A.hashcode == B.hashcode then A.equals(B)
   }

 }

 public class TrackDataCache {

   private WeakHashMap<Integer,TrackData> cache = new WeakHashMap<Integer,TrackData>();

   public TrackData getTrackData(Track track) {

     // cache contains shared TrackData instances, we may throw away
     // the Track instance in favour of the shared one.

     Integer key = track.getTrackData().hashcode();

     TrackData data = cache.get(key);

     if (data == null) {

       cache.put(key, track.getTrackData());
       data = track.getTrackData();

     } else {

       // ensure we're using the shared instance, not the local one.
       // deliberate object reference comparison  
       if (data != track.getTrackData()) {
         track.setTrackData(data);
       } 

     }

     return data;

   }

 }
```

Notice that the `WeakHashMap` will not do anything in any of the two solutions as long as there are `Track` objects alive keeping references to the `TrackData`. This could be fixed by making `WeakReference` inside `Track` - however that also means you can end up not having any `TrackData`, and need to read it back from file, in which case the first solution is better modelled than the second.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. `getTrackData` is just a getter, it is not expensive. I need this cache because several tracks can point to the same TrackData, i.e. a track is just an entry in the playlist, so I can have multiple copies of the track pointing to the same TrackData. So I need cache to be able to share objects, not speed up access time.

Comment: @tulskiy, Hm. Do you add `TrackData` into `Track` using constructor/ setter or it calculates using other fields?

Comment: @Stas Kurilin: it is created when I read tags and other info from file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can override Tracks' equals method. I sometimes need to rely on different instances of tracks with same data to be different.