# Why there is no WeakList and WeakSet implementation in Java?

Tags: java, collections, weak-references

... at least not "official".

You can easily google two or three "WeakList" example implementation and for "WeakSet" one very good can be found in [NetBeans Platform API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/WeakSet.html) sources.

I read [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062919/why-does-exist-weakhashmap-but-absent-weakset) placed here asking for WeakSet. Answers were "there is no usecase for WeakSet". If it will be like this why these unofficial implementations exist?

Comment: Probably because such data-structures are quite specialized -- not that there isn't *a* (contrived-existing-somewhere) use-case so much as that it's only for a *very* specific niche not warranting inclusion into the standard library. Including it into the base Java library would also force all [certified] Java run-times to include it, increasing size (bytecode) and code (complexity) -- it's not "free" to make something part of the standard libraries. (There are so many more "common" features I find missing :-/)

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you can get one by using `Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap())`. Many collections don't exist as public classes (if they are not-so-important), but can be obtained by the `Collections` factory methods.