# Set equivalent of WeakHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashset, weak-references, weakhashmap

Is `HashSet<WeakReference<T>>` the `Set` equivalent of `WeakHashMap<T>`? That is, will entries be *automatically* deleted when they are no longer referenced?

If not, what is the equivalent?

Comment: Believe this is what you might be looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4062950/717932

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does exist WeakHashMap, but absent WeakSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062919/why-does-exist-weakhashmap-but-absent-weakset)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The other question attempts to answer why there is no WeakSet. It doesn't provide a Set equivalent, nor does it answer whether my example above counts as an equivalent.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, if an object referenced by one of the `WeakReference`s in the set gets garbage-collected, the `WeakReference` will still be included in the set and will not be removed automatically, but their `referent` will be `null`. A `WeakHashMap` uses additional code to remove the weakly referenced keys from the map when they're garbage-collected.

A set equivalent of a `WeakHashMap` is:

```
Set<T> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<T, Boolean>());
```

As a `HashSet` also uses a `HashMap` internally.

BTW: A  `WeakReference` is just an object pointing to an object which may be garbage-collected despite the reference held by the `WeakReference`. The `WeakReference` itself will not be garbage-collected until it is not strongly referenced anywhere anymore just like all other objects.